# Change my favorite tags for me

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags

When a tag is changed or merged, I'd like my existing tags to also be changed, not to come up with a blank query.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't say this is a bug, since tags aren't deleted. Some user can still post a question in that tag, he'll just see that there are no other questions tagged that.

Comment: Maybe not in your programming mind, but this is 'breaking' my use experience.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's a feature request.